# How to assign the value from an HTML Element as value of a variable defined in MVC Modal class in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am exploring CRUD Operations in MVC using ADO.Net in order to store the employee record and manipulate them as per necessity.
As I defined the table columns in Model, the MVC generates the view accordingly which generated HTML helper but not normal html elements. So now I have this html element:
   `<input type="text" id="datepicker">` 
This text box gets a string of datetime from the datepicker jQuery API. Now I have defined it in view model as

```
   [Display(Name ="Travel Days")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
```

Now I want to perform an operation to pass the value **Date** to the database. For this I have performed certain operations here:

```
public bool AddEmpInfo(EmpInfoModels Info)
        {
            using (connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CrudMvc"].ToString()))
            {

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AddEmpInfo", connect);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Info.Date);
                connect.Open();
                int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i >0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

As I debug the process, the value submitted from the view class is not received with the Info.Date.

So my problem is to bind the value entered from a plain html element and send it as a parameter to the stored procedure to perform database operations.

Comment: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date">

Comment: Use `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your html correctly - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)` which will add the correct `name` attribute for binding (but why in the world is it a `string` instead of `DateTime`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke He is using string because we are having problem for a long time with date format where in our Subcontinent(South Asia) we use "dd/mm/yyyy" which is by default not support by the controller.

Comment: @Mir, That has nothing to do with it. All that's need to set the culture on the server and the `DefaultModelBinder` will correctly bind it (or create a custom `ModelBinder` (never use `string` for a `DateTime`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah I know that. But not every starter knows that and they get stuck and finds string did the trick for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add name to bind with Model

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date">
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC/Web Api Model binding can happen in three ways:

1. **From Query string** 
   Consider you are passing values in query string - `http://your_domain/controller_name/youraction?id=100` - the id will be bound to your action parameter named "id", for eg, `public ActionResult YourAction(int id)`.
   You can even bind an object using query string values, for eg, url - `http://your_domain/controller_name/youraction?id=100&name=your_name&age=30` & action `public ActionResult YourAction([FromUrl]Employee employee)` ,provided Employee class has id, name and age properties
2. **From Route values** - self explanatory, from the values you have specified in routes. In case of attribute routing, if we take the first scenario above, the action would look like:
   `[Route("YourAction/{id}')]
    public ActionResult YourAction(int id)`
3. **From FormData** - Putting it in simpler terms, when a form is submitted, model binder finds the elements whose *name* matches the property names and binds the value. For eg, if you want to bind an Employee object (which has Id, Name and Age properties) on form submit to an action, say, 
   `[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourAction(Employee employee)`

   you should have 3 html elements with the corresponding names like, 
   `<input type="text" name="Name" />`
   `<input type="hidden" name="Id" />` 
    `<input type="number" name="Age" />`

This is exactly what @Html helpers do, they will assign the "name" attribute of the element to match the Model property.

So in your case, to bind value to "Date" property, you should have a html element with `name="Date"`